# Sending data throug Ajax and processing them on an action controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send some geolocation data via Ajax and process them on a specific action of a controller.

The code (which is in the view) looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/save_location",
        data: "lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&long=" +  
            position.coords.longitude
});
```

I have a `save_location` action which is located in the `users controller`:

```
 def save_temp_location
    cookies[:lat] = params[:lat]
    cookies[:long] = params[:long]
 end
```

I want to save those data temporarily while the user is browsing the site. Inside my view I have tried to display the values of `cookies[:lat]` and `cookies[:long]` to check whether it worked or not: Unfortunately, nothing is displayed. I looked at the console the GET request is made (the route is correct):

```
Started GET "/save_location?lat=48.856666&long=2.350987" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-09 12:02:25 +0100
  Processing by UsersController#save_temp_location as 
  Parameters: {"lat"=>"48.856666", "long"=>"2.350987"}
Redirected to http://fr.localhost.dev:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms
```

I tried debugging by placing a: `puts "foo"`  or `raise "foo"` in that action but nothing happens (however I do get the appropriate behaviour when browsing manually to /save_location). Does the `302 http code`, have something to do with that? (and what does it mean in this context?).

What do you think is wrong? Am I missing a very important point?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the status code of 302 (and hence the redirect) by design? Could you switch that off and try the ajax call once again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you be redirected by a filter ?